# Plane-object displayed in background while beeing in front (Eevee Viewport)

Tags: 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

Some plane-objects are being displayed in the background while being in front. Is this a bug or am i missing something Eevee-specific?

[image]
[image]

All the plane objects were joined while uv-projecting from top-ortho view with bounds, so they have overlapping uvs. Maybe this has something to do with it, because i never had this behavior in any other case.

edit: It has something to do with all the parts having the same material. With different materials the error doesn't occur, but i would prefer to not manually create different materials for all the parts in this workflow.

edit2: I recognized that the AddOn "import image as plane" by default sets the material to "alpha blend", what was the reason for the "overlapping".
(Is there a possibility to remove the overlapping while keeping alpha blend, just in case?)

Win7, Blender 2.81
[image]

Comment: it has to do with the blend modes. make sure all objects are on opaque and not on alpha blend or alpha hashed.