# PNGs in distance appear to overlap foreground PNGs when viewed at different angles

Tags: add-on

Unless I'm doing something wrong, I think this is a bug.

Large PNGs imported as planes render strangely in both the viewport and final render (Eevee). I had this same issue in 2.80 and now using 2.81. Using Windows 10.

When seen face on (top image) things look good but when the angle to the plane is tighter (2nd image) you get distant PNGs which are technically behind objects *appearing* in front of them.

Most of these PNGs are 30,000 pixels wide, with an alpha mask.

I use the add-on **import images as planes**, and import with Emit setting (see shader node settings below). Blend mode: alpha blend.

I've uploaded [a short video here](https://youtu.be/DbzGJ6502x0). You can see the problems starting from 20 secs. Before then everything is fine.

Thanks.

[image: at near to 90 to the plane, everything is fine]

[image: at tighter angles things get strange]

[image: shader nodes]

Comment: Does the effect change if, at the first  problematic frame, you change the near / far clipping distances on the camera?

Comment: Tried that already thanks. No difference.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the "import image as plane" addon sets the material Blend Mode to "alpha blend" by default. Switching it to "opaque" resolves the issue.

[image]

How to solve this with "alpha blend" on is also open in my related question: [Plane-object displayed in background while beeing in front (Eevee Viewport)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160231/plane-object-displayed-in-background-while-beeing-in-front-eevee-viewport)

Comment: Thanks. I can't use opaque because each PNG has an alpha mask. But you were close! I changed Blend mode to alpha clip, and it worked. I still think it's a bug, but this will do.