# Texture is "inverted" when object has a face in front of another face

Tags: texturing, uv, faces, eevee-render-engine

It's kind of hard to explain what's going on. I sketched a flower in Photoshop, saved it as an image, and imported it as a plane. From some directions, its transparent depth is inverted.

I knifed a couple extra points on it so I could "cup" it like an actual flower.

When you view it where you can see all the faces, it looks just like I wanted:

[image: Flower looking "normal"]

The problem is when you view the flower at an angle where a face overlaps another face between the camera, the **rear** face shows in front:

[image]

The blue petal should be fully in front of the red petal, but when you look from a lower angle, the red petal seems to show in front of the blue one? I didn't do anything fancy - just Image as Plane > Knife some points > move them around.

Comment: If EEVEE.. (maybe tag your question)... could be similar to [this problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/160389/35559). Does switching to Alpha Hashed make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't sure, it was just in Viewport Shading: Rendered (whatever the default is). That was the issue though! Alpha Hashed fixed the issue - thanks for pointing me in that direction!

Comment: Cool. EEVEE is used as the full renderer by default on startup, (and always for Material Preview mode).. switched in the 'Render' tab of the Properties region. I won't turn the comment into an answer.. someone out there might be able to explain _why_ this happens.